# how to show that an homomorphism is a surjection?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know for example to show that an homomorphis is injective you has to prove that $ker f = \{0 \}$ but what in case of surjective? that is all the elements of the codomain have a preimage.

Comment: Take a point in the codomain, find a point in the domain that maps to it.

Comment: What structures are You talking about exactly?

Comment: I do not think, that there is a general good answer for this. For example if you have a homomorphism $f: A\to B$, where $A$ and $B$ both are finite, it is enough to show, that $f$ is injective, to show, that it is also surjective. Else you have to go by definition.

Comment: The symmetric way of showing a homomorphism is surjective would be to show that the cokernel is trivial, but in practice, it's easier to check that every element has a preimage.

Comment: The related notion to kernel is cokernel; you would need to show $\text{coker}\,(f)=\{0\}$